# elseif ($var = '0') not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to implement a bank system on a game project of mine. I'm having a problem with `elseif`.

I have this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('include/dbconnect.php');
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow = mysql_fetch_array($res);    
$in = $_POST['entrar'];
$pocketremain = ($userRow['money'] - $in);
$bankremain = ($userRow['bank'] + $in);

if ($in < $userRow['money']) {
    // QUERIES
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money ='".$pocketremain."'     WHERE user_id ='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET bank ='".$bankremain."' WHERE     user_id ='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
    $string = "<br><font size='2'><font color='green'>SUCCESS !!    </font><br>You deposited $in$.<br>You now have $bankremain$ in the Bank<br>and     $pocketremain$ in your Pocket.</font>";
} elseif ($in <= '0') { // FIM DE QUERIES
    $string = "<br><font size='2'><font color='red'>FAIL !!</font>     <br>You cant deposit imaginary money!</font>";
} else {
    $string = "<br><font size='2'><font color='red'>FAIL !!</font>     <br>Your values are Wrong!</font>";
}   
?>
```

I still can depoisit Zero money in the bank. `elseif` should be stating that `$string` if 0 was set as value.
If you could kill this for me I would appreciate, i have been trying to work around this for hours now.

Comment: `elseif ($var = '0')` sounds not correct since `$var = '0'` assignment. what you want probably is `$var == '0' `

Comment: Are we presuming first that `$_SESSION['user']` is an integer and has already been ecaped?

Comment: I think you should test `$in <= 0` before `$in < $userRow['money']`. Both can be true at the same time.

Comment: [You're vulnerable to SQL injection when you use $_POST in that way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). [You should stop using the mysql_* library of functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Use **elseif ($in <= '0')** instead of **elseif ($in == '0')**

You are getting an error because you are assigning a value (**0** in this case) to in $in when you use **($in = '0')**. To compare you should use a double **==**.

**==** Will check to see if $val is equal to 0

**<=** Will check to see if $val is equal to, or less than 0

**=** Will assign 0 to val

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one condition in your `if` statement. Your code should be

```
if ($in < $userRow['money'] && $in > 0) {
// QUERIES
                mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money ='".$pocketremain."'     WHERE user_id ='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
                mysql_query("UPDATE users SET bank ='".$bankremain."' WHERE     user_id ='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
                $string = "<br><font size='2'><font color='green'>SUCCESS !!    </font><br>You deposited $in$.<br>You now have $bankremain$ in the Bank<br>and     $pocketremain$ in your Pocket.</font>";
}
// FIM DE QUERIES
    elseif ($in <= '0') {
        $string = "<br><font size='2'><font color='red'>FAIL !!</font>     <br>You cant deposit imaginary money!</font>";
    }
    else {
        $string = "<br><font size='2'><font color='red'>FAIL !!</font>     <br>Your values are Wrong!</font>";
    }
```

Because when your `$in` is `0 or less than 0` then your first `if statement` is `true`, So It didn't go in to your second `elseif` statement.